# Propper Collapseable Sidebar design / 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Window'

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am making a collapsible sidebar using React Typescript this is my current layout thoughts. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Also, I get a red squiggle under "prev" with the error I think it is a JS > TS caused error but I am unsure how to fix it myself.

```
(parameter) prev: Window | null
Argument of type '(prev: Window | null) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Window | null>'.
  Type '(prev: Window | null) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Window | null) => Window | null'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Window'
```

The program still runs but how can I fix this error?

```
import "./SidePanel.css"
import {useState} from 'react'
const SidePanel = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(open);

  const handleFilterOpening = () => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };
    return (
        <nav id="Side-Panel-Wrapper">
            {!isOpen ? (
                <div>
                <div className="Side-Panel-Top-Bar-Wrapper-Open">
                <button>Logo</button>
                <button onClick={handleFilterOpening}>Close</button>
            </div>
            <div className="Side-Pannel-Navigation-Main-Wrapper-Open">
                search stuff
            </div>
            </div>
              ) : (
                <div>
                    <div className="Side-Panel-Top-Bar-Wrapper-Closed">
           
                <button onClick={handleFilterOpening}>Close</button>
            </div>
            <div className="Side-Pannel-Navigation-Main-Wrapper-Closed">
                logo
            </div>
                </div>
              )}
            
        </nav>
    )
  };
  
  export default SidePanel;
```

Comment: The error may be connected with the fact  return value isn't of expected typing. Haven't you tried to set initial state to `false` and toggle it `setIsOpen(!isOpen)`? The initial state is `null` at the moment

Comment: I managed to fix it using const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<any|null>(open);

  const handleFilterOpening = () => {
    setIsOpen((prev:any) => !prev);